# Aluminum Electrolytic Capacitor Venting Creating Condensation in Enclosure

Tags: capacitor

Has anyone ever come across significant condensation on electrical components inside an enclosure due to venting of aluminum electrolytic capacitors ? My 560uf 400V Chang capacitors (believed to be aluminum elec.) have vented, and there is significant water condensation in my enclosure. I suspect the venting was caused by water ingress (< IP55) which shorted the capacitors, but I want to make sure that the venting discharge isn't the cause of the water condensation.

As anyone else experienced something similar ?

Comment: Unless you had a lot of contaminants on your board that dissolved into the condensation, it seems unlikely that your caps shorted out due to condensation.  Condensed moisture is relative high resistance.  It seems more likely that the caps were over stressed and vented, and that is the condensation that you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I've had *old* water-based electrolytics vent, releasing a small amount of both pure water, condensed from that which boiled off, and of spattered electrolyte. The spattered electrolyte is more conductive and somewhat more corrosive than the water, so must be cleaned thoroughly.

That said, [most modern electrolytic capacitors are of the "dry" type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolytic_capacitor#%22Dry%22_aluminum_capacitor), having *little water content*, so if you've noticed a *lot of moisture*, it likely came from somewhere else and preceded the demise of the caps.

Moisture could have caused failure both through corrosion or by providing a conductive path. For example, if two 400 VDC capacitors are in series, with parallel balancing resistors on the order of 100 kΩ, and moisture provides a path across one resistor, the PCB or one capacitor, it might cause 750 V to appear across the other capacitor, and 50 V across the "shorted" one. Worse yet, look for charring [where the water provided a path](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6cjp0yvAiY) for HV.

Comment: The water ingress seems to be the issue with condensation. ALso water+dust can reduce breakdown voltage significantly from creepage.